# jquery each returning an operator error message in console

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to POST to create a PHP session cart, and then GET the session in a sidebar cart to display. I'm close, the alerts work fine, but I can't figure out why my data is being retrieved as anything but a json string.

Here's the console error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"orders":{"testfive.net":{"domain_order":{"addnew":{"years":"9"}}},"testone.biz":{"domain_order":{"addnew":{"years":"1"}}}}}

And here's the JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //add to cart
    $(".add_domain").on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $domain_name = $this.find('input.domain_name').val();
    var $years = $this.find('select.addnew_period').val();

    var obj = { domain_name: $domain_name, years: $years};
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
    alert(myJSON);

    //POST to the cart
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('orders/addtocart'); ?>',
            myJSON,
            function (data, status) {
                alert("Data Results: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });

    //GET the cart contents
    var $sidebar = '<ul>';
    $.get('<?php echo site_url('orders/getcart'); ?>', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(element) {
           $sidebar += '<li>' + element.domain_name + '</li>';
          });  
          $sidebar += '</ul>';
        $("div.sidecart").html($sidebar);        
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, by switching to $.getJSON.  Here's the whole GET request for reference:

```
//GET the cart contents
$.getJSON('<?php echo site_url('orders/getcart'); ?>', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function (domain, detail) {
        $.each(detail.domain_order, function (key, val) {
            if(key === 'addnew') {
                //alert("domain: "+domain+" years: "+val.years);
                items.push("<li id='" + domain + "'>" + domain +" for "+val.years + " Year(s)</li>");
            }
        });
    });
    $("<ul/>", {
        "class": "cart-list",
        html: items.join("")
    }).appendTo("div.sidecart");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
 //GET the cart contents
        var $sidebar = '<ul>';
        $.get('<?php echo site_url('orders/getcart'); ?>', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, value) { // You just use 2 parameter 
               $sidebar += '<li>' + element.domain_name + '</li>';
              });  
              $sidebar += '</ul>';
            $("div.sidecart").html($sidebar);        
        });
```

Comment: You didn't change anything except to add an index, and you're not using either index or value in the result loop.  What did you expect to be different?